# Python.el mishandling my M-q indentations on docstrings

Tags: python, emacs

Given a function

```
def foo():
  """
  etc
  stuff
  """
  pass
```

when I run M-q to paragraph up my docstrings, emacs (24.3.1, python.el) will reformat foo like this:

```
def foo():
  """etc
  stuff
  """
  pass
```

How do I tell python.el to leave it alone? (I know this behavior is new, an older emacs on a different computer (that I don't have access to) didn't do this).

Comment: That is actually the Python convention, albeit missing a blank line - see [PEP-0257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Searching the [source code for `python.el`](https://github.com/fgallina/python.el/blob/master/python.el) indicates that `'python-fill-docstring-style'` is the parameter you're looking for (you probably want `'nil'` or `'symmetric'`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Ah, thanks for the variable tip. I actually want DJANGO.

Comment: Swing and a miss! No problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - haha, no problem. Put your comment down as an answer, and I'll mark it correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `python.el` is doing is actually the Python convention (albeit without a blank line after the first line) - see [PEP-0257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)'s example:

```
def complex(real=0.0, imag=0.0):
    """Form a complex number.

    Keyword arguments:
    real -- the real part (default 0.0)
    imag -- the imaginary part (default 0.0)
    """
    if imag == 0.0 and real == 0.0:
        return complex_zero
```

Looking at [the source code for `python.el`](https://github.com/fgallina/python.el/blob/master/python.el), the parameter to alter this behaviour is `'python-fill-docstring-style'`, which defaults to `pep-257` but offers some alternatives:

```
:type '(choice
          (const :tag "Don't format docstrings" nil)
          (const :tag "Django's coding standards style." django)
          (const :tag "One newline and start and Two at end style." onetwo)
          (const :tag "PEP-257 with 2 newlines at end of string." pep-257)
          (const :tag "PEP-257 with 1 newline at end of string." pep-257-nn)
          (const :tag "Symmetric style." symmetric))
```

Comment: Ironically, the example you cited from PEP 257 is actually filled incorrectly by Emacs: the keyword argument list is collapsed to a single line. Is there a way to fix this?